# lambda function with if...else in agg on dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I am trying to calculate aggregate using a lambda function with if... else.

My dataframe looks like this

```
    States  Sales
0   Delhi   0.0
1   Kerala  2.5
2   Punjab  5.0
3   Haryana 7.5
4   Delhi   10.0
5   Kerala  12.5
6   Punjab  15.0
7   Haryana 17.5
```

Expected summary table should like this

```
States  Sales
Delhi   10.0
Haryana 25.0
Kerala  15.0
Punjab  20.0
```

I tried using the following code

```
df.groupby('States').agg({
                    'Sales':lambda x: np.sum(x) if (x>7) else 0
                    })
```

I get ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: I had seen that earlier, but didn't solve my issue

Comment: How did it not solve the issue?  It is exactly that issue, as the below answers also demonstrate.  You need to use `(x > 7).any()` for example.

Comment: True, my bad..... I could not apply the suggestions in the post as demonstrated by posts below. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

If compare by `(x>7)` ouput is `Series` with `True` and `False`s, for test if match at least value use `any`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('States').agg({'Sales':lambda x: np.sum(x) if (x>7).any() else 0})
print (df1)
         Sales
States        
Delhi     10.0
Haryana   25.0
Kerala    15.0
Punjab    20.0
```

If need replace all values lower or equal like `7` to `0` and then aggregate `sum` use:

```
df2 = df['Sales'].where(df['Sales'].gt(7), 0).to_frame().groupby(df['States']).sum()
print (df2)
         Sales
States        
Delhi     10.0
Haryana   25.0
Kerala    12.5
Punjab    15.0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, for both options!

Comment: @jezrael. 
Just curious, how should we approach this if we want to filter based on the value of a different column (say column C)  and not based on aggregated value of the column C?

Comment: @tjt - if change `df['Sales'].where(df['Sales'].gt(7), 0)` to `df['Sales'].where(df['Another col'].gt(7), 0)` it working?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. I think that will do.
Is there a way to approach the following slight different question - (using the group by on states) if 'another col' gt (7) do sum, if lt(7) do avg or even cumsum. 
Sorry, I know this thread is for the main question posted and I am diverting.

Answer (score 1):

```
 df.groupby('States')['Sales'].agg(lambda x: sum(x) if x.ge(7).any() else 0).to_frame('Sales')

         Sales
States       
Delhi    10.0
Haryana  25.0
Kerala   15.0
Punjab   20.0
```

Comment: Thanks @wwnde, that worked!